# Mismatching Python and MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, statistics

I have starting to fit lognormal distribution to my data, but I was a bit sceptical about the results I got. So, I double checked it with MATLAB and found completely different results. The fitting parameters are no way close to each other in Python and MATLAB. So, I came up to do another test I fitted normal distribution to np.log of data, and surprisingly the fitting parameters matched but unfortunately once I tried to get their corresponding pdf through dist.pdf(np.log(X)) it gave me different results. I also checked forums for this problem and found that there was bug in scipy version 0.9, but I already upgraded my package to 1.11.4. So I would appreciate it if someone could help me in this regard.

All response are appreciated

```
X = [3.5, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 3.5, 2.1, 1.4, 2.8, 3.5, 2.1, 3.5, 2.1, 5.6, 4.9]
```

Python:

```py
from scipy.stats import lognorm, norm
import numpy as np

params = lognorm.fit(X)

(16.51366131539468, 1.3999999999999997, 4.788960501713848e-05)

dist = lognorm(*params)
dist.pdf(X)

array([9.32987767e-03, 3.12114067e+13, 3.12114067e+13, 3.12114067e+13,
   9.32987767e-03, 2.91566052e-02, 3.12114067e+13, 1.42147170e-02,
   9.32987767e-03, 2.91566052e-02, 9.32987767e-03, 2.91566052e-02,
   4.53591043e-03, 5.48433565e-03])

norm.fit(np.log(X))

array([0.923, 0.463])
```

MATLAB

```matlab
lognfit(X)

ans =

0.9232    0.4807

>> dist.pdf(ere)'

ans =

0.1875    0.2815    0.2815    0.2815    0.1875    0.3681    0.2815    0.2892    0.1875    
0.3681    0.1875    0.3681    0.0372    0.0649
```

Comment: SciPy returns the maximum likelihood estimate of the parameters. Matlab does not; it returns the square root of the unbiased sample variance for the scale. Also, when fitting the lognormal in SciPy, you have to pass `floc=0` if you want the location to be fixed at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a MCVE showing how to make the correspondancy:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(123456)

law = stats.lognorm(s=1.2, loc=0., scale=np.exp(1))
data = law.rvs(3000)

p = stats.lognorm.fit(data, floc=0.)
# (1.1912036427424741, 0.0, 2.7432911737748293)

np.log(p[-1]) # 1.0091583578984649

stats.norm.fit(np.log(data))
# (1.0091583578984649, 1.1912036427424741)
```

So basically you need two things:

- fix the `floc` parameters to zero
- use the `log` of `scale` the parameter regressed by `lognorm.fit`.

With your example it gives:

```py
x = [3.5, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 3.5, 2.1, 1.4, 2.8, 3.5, 2.1, 3.5, 2.1, 5.6, 4.9]
    
p = stats.lognorm.fit(x, floc=0.)
# (0.4632376775596644, 0.0, 2.5172563962150667)

np.log(p[-1]) # 0.9231695767638068

stats.norm.fit(np.log(x))
# (0.923169576763807, 0.4632376775596644)
```